# Create a Task list, with tasks without executing

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, async-await

I have an async method

```
private async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken token)
```

a list of Tasks

```
private List<Task> workers = new List<Task>();
```

and I have to create N threads that runs that method

```
public void CreateThreads(int n)
{
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    token = tokenSource.Token;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        workers.Add(DoSomething(token));
    }
}
```

but the problem is that those have to run at a given time

```
public async Task StartAllWorkers()
{
    if (workers.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            while (workers.Count > 0)
            {
                Task finishedWorker = await Task.WhenAny(workers.ToArray());
                workers.Remove(finishedWorker);
                finishedWorker.Dispose();
            }
            if (workers.Count == 0)
            {
                tokenSource = null;
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

but actually they run when i call the CreateThreads Method (before the StartAllWorkers).
I searched for keywords and problems like mine but couldn't find anything about stopping the task from running.
I've tried a lot of different aproaches but anything that could solve my problem entirely.
For example, moving the code from `DoSomething` into a `workers.Add(new Task(async () => { }, token));` would run the `StartAllWorkers()`, but the threads will never actually start.

There is another method for calling the `tokenSource.Cancel()`.

Comment: CreateThreads doesn't create threads; StartAllWorkers doesn't start any workers; DoSomething sounds interesting, but we can only guess at what it does because you don't show it...

Comment: You have to change your DoSomethimg. It Looks like you are calling Task.StartNew. Try Task myTask = new Task() instead.

Comment: Please change `if (0 < workers.Count)` to `if (workers.Count > 0)`. I really had to do a double take to figure out what it meant...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` as a one-time "signal" to asynchronous methods.

So you'd create it like this:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs;
public void CreateThreads(int n)
{
    _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    token = tokenSource.Token;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        workers.Add(DoSomething(_tcs.Task, token));
    }
}
```

Then when you're ready to start the tasks, just complete the "start" signal task:

```
public Task StartAllWorkers()
{
    _tcs.TrySetCompleted(null);
    return Task.WhenAll(workers);
}
```

(The `StartAllWorkers` method above has *slightly* different semantics than your original method: your original method would throw a cancellation exception as soon as the first task canceled; this one will wait until all the methods complete and then throw a cancellation exception)

Then your `DoSomething` just has to honor the "start signal":

```
private static async Task DoSomething(Task start, CancellationToken token)
{
    await start;
    ... // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: All the threads share the same cancellation token, so all should be canceled when one is canceled.
I'll test this and let you know if it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

What about this idea:

Instead of holding a list of tasks, hold a list of TaskReference items:

```
public class TaskReference
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _func;

    public TaskReference(Func<Task> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        await _func();
    }
}
```

Adding to the list works like this:

```
taskList.Add(new TaskReference(() => DoSomething(myToken)));
```

And execution like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(taskList.Select(o => o.RunAsync()));
```

Comment: There's no real need for the extra class here.  Just have `taskList` be a `LIst<Func<Task>>` and invoke the delegates to start the operations.  Your class isn't adding any additional value.

Comment: Good point! Well maybe it adds a bit of clarity to the code as without the class you might be wondering why one would use a Func<Task> instead of a Task directly. The class documentation could shed some light into this. But apart from that, you are right, it does not add value. The value comes from the Func<Task> idea